# Earliest possible date for a folder / file attribute?

Tags: windows-explorer, file-attributes

Just for some context, so people understand why I'm doing what I'm doing...

My movie collection is stored in this fashion;

```
Movies (folder)
 |---- Movie title, Year released (folder)
       |---- Movie title (file)
```

This means all my movies are stored in alphabetical order, which is (usually) great, as I generally know what I want to watch and can just search for (or scroll to) it.

However, as a requirement for another project, I downloaded [Attribute Changer](https://www.petges.lu/). This app - unsurprisingly - allows you to change the attributes of files and folders.

To give me some more options for movie storage and sorting, I have been working my way through my films, and editing the `Date Modified` and `Date Created` attributes to the release date of the film. This gives me the option to sort by release date, so if I decide I want to watch a new film, but don't necessarily have a film in mind, I can easily sort by newest releases.

Now, actually onto my question - what is the earliest date that a file / folder could have as its created / modified date? I just tried to set a films date to [6th October 1962 (Dr. No)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dr%20no), but Windows explorer is now showing the `Date Modified` as blank. If I open the folder properties (right click > Properties) then it shows the correct date, it just seems to be explorer which doesn't like it.

EDIT: I thought it might be something to do with [Unix time beginning in 1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), however I have tried dates after 1970 and I'm still getting a blank space in Windows explorer.

Comment: Just found a dupe after a bit more digging... https://superuser.com/q/796762/

Comment: I would just like to point out that they have software that does this for you. It identifies and assists with downloading metadata for movies and other media in your collection. It's been a little while since I used mine, so I can't think of the name right off hand. But if they are all named it will easily download all the associated metadata including cover images, etc.