# Why does Windows Explorer show no file created or modified date?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I ripped some Warner Brothers cartoons and then used MacOS's `touch -t` command to set the file creation and modification dates to the release dates for the cartoons.  (This is to get Plex to display the correct year for the videos.) When I use File Explorer on a Windows 10 machine to view the directory on the Mac where the files are stored, it shows no creation or modification dates:

[image]

But if I bring up the Properties for any of the files, the creation and modification dates are shown:

[image]

How can I get File Explorer to show the creation and modification dates?

Comment: I would use Windows software to modify it instead of macOS software or just PowerShell. $(Get-Item file-name.file-extension).creationtime=$(Get-Date “mm/dd/yyyy”

Comment: The modifications have already been made. The question is why the usual FE view shows no data, while the Properties dialog of FE shows that the data is there.

Comment: Likely has to do with file preview handler in part. If you move the file to a non-network drive does file explorer show the date?

Comment: Copying the files to a local drive yields a blank modification date in FE list view. It's present in the Properties dialog, as before. The creation and access dates in FE list view are the current date, i.e., the date/time that the copy was created.

Comment: Try setting a date 1970 or later instead. My theory is Explorer can't properly 'see' dates before unix time. I just tested Mac to VM Win - https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCLYS.png - I used [A Better Finder Attributes](https://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderAttributes/version.html) not terminal, so I know there was no error.

Comment: Hmm… haven't honed it down any further, but Jan 70 still doesn't show, Jan 80 does. It's definitely something to do with 'how old' it purports to be.

Comment: **Found it!** Windows is pegged at 1 Jan 80 - see https://superuser.com/q/796762/347380 That means you need to be setting your dates in EXIF.

Comment: Are the same values blank in cmd.exe or PowerShell? if so, then the file system properties are blank/invalid format. So the dates have to be coming from, as @tetjin noted, from EXIF. Have you tried adding "Media created" (or other likely suspects) in an **Explorer** Details view? If you determine the source, a simple **PoweShell** script could update the file system properties to match.

Comment: @KeithMiller: In PowerShell, `dir` shows all files with a `LastWriteTime` of `12/31/1969 4:00 PM`. The creation and modification times I set using `touch` are all in the 1950s.

Answer (score 2):

As Tetsujin deducted with his experiments, the SMB protocol is indeed limited regarding the timestamps it can transport in some locations. In the [MS-CIFS](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-CIFS/%5bMS-CIFS%5d.pdf) protocol specification, the following information is available:

> ### 2.2.1.4.1 SMB_DATE
>
> This is a 16-bit value in little-endian byte order used to encode a date. An SMB_DATE value SHOULD be interpreted as follows. The date is represented in the local time zone of the server. The following field names are provided for reference only.
>
> | Field name and bitmask | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | YEAR 0xFE00 | The year. Add 1980 to the resulting value to return the actual year.<17> |
> | MONTH 0x01E0 | The month. Values range from 1 to 12. |
> | DAY 0x001F | The date. Values range from 1 to 31. |

With note 17 being:

> The maximum value permitted in the SMB_DATE.YEAR field is 119,
> resulting in a year range of 1980 to 2099.

Also:

> ### 2.2.1.4.3 UTIME
>
> This is a 32-bit unsigned integer in little-endian byte order indicating the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00.0.
>
> This type is declared as follows:
>
> ```
> typedef unsigned int UTIME;
> ```

*UTIME* is the “modern” variant while *SMB_DATE* is mostly used in deprecated legacy commands.

However, that’s not all. In other places, the [*FILETIME*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) type is used, described as:

> Contains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

So Explorer could be using one of the old types to list directories but one of the new types when querying extended metadata (including ACLs).

---

Either way, from an objective viewpoint, you’re going about this the wrong way. Filesystem metadata (like the modified data) is not about file contents. It is about the file. You could add the correct information *inside* the file, using tags. Both MP4 and MKV containers support this.

Media center software may not look at that, though. So instead (or additionally), you should add the year to the filename, e.g. “Sahara Hare (1955).mkv”. This is universally accepted by all media center software.

Comment: FYI: The file sytem date/time values in **Windows Explorer** are encoded in the `FIleTime` format in ShellLinks (.lnk - shortcut files), iDLs, and most likely everywhere else

Comment: Thanks for providing the fuller explanation. I just had a theory I poked with a stick until an apple fell. ;)

Comment: I agree that content metadata belongs in the file, not the file system, but for videos, Plex pulls the year it displays from the file's modification date.  I'll see if there is a way use metadata in the video files to address this issue.

Comment: Not sure where you got that from or what you’re seeing. I’m referring to the [Plex documentation on movie file naming](https://support.plex.tv/articles/naming-and-organizing-your-movie-media-files/).

Comment: After more investigation, it looks like Plex uses the file modification date as the video date only by default. The default can be overridden by [editing the video details](https://support.plex.tv/articles/201272763-edit-details/), which I've now done and which yields the results I want.